# Using AutoLayout makes UIView opaque

Tags: uiview, autolayout

In Apple Developer's [SquareCam sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), in `MainStoryBoard` if *Use AutoLayout* is checked, the camera view doesn't remain transparent and we aren't able to see the object we intend to take a picture of.

I.e. it becomes opaque, but the picture gets taken. What needs to be done so the view doesn't become opaque when *Use AutoLayout* is checked?